# What 3DES Encryption mode does IIS use (CBC, ECB, OFB)?

Tags: iis

My understanding is that that 3DES can be configured to use multiple modes including **cipher block chaining** (CBC) and **electronic code book** (ECB).

Does anyone know which one is [used by IIS whenever 3DES is configured](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772271(v=ws.10).aspx) in the machineKey?